# Android application publish error

Tags: android

[image]I have uploaded an android application on play store. The status of application is published but when i install this application from play store it crash. Unfrotunately, BMk has stopped[image].This is the link of application.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mudasar.tariq

Comment: Report it, and check the crash report in your developer console. Atleast you will come to know the error and cause of that error.

Comment: Thanks for the response i will try this. Ravi Rupareliya

Comment: If you would debugg  app store apllication via usb I'm sure it will show stacktrace off the error inside android monitor

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mudasar.tariq.mudasar.bmi.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mudasar.tariq-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/mudasar.tariq-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: This is what i recived in crashes & ANRs

Answer (score -2):

Please insert fire base crash analytics on your application and publish it on Google play. This sends the cause of crash to your fire base console

Comment: Firebase? The OP never mentioned firebase in his post?

Comment: He didn't mention the cause of crash also, then tell me how to find the cause of crash?